# Is there a way to import a recipient's address from mutt into abook?

Tags: mutt

I am using abook as my addressbook with mutt. I have set up a Macro that lets me import the sender's address from an e-mail via the `abook --add-email` command:

`macro index,pager A "<pipe-message>abook --add-email<return>" "add the sender address to abook"`

I also receive e-mail that is addressed to others, too, and in these cases it happens that I need to import one or several addresses into abook. the `--add-emai` command only reads sender's addresses (even those of forwarded mail if the right header has been forwarded too).

Is there an easy way, that is just using mutt and abook, no additional script, to import recipient's addresses into abook?
And if not, how can it be done (how do you do it?)?

Comment: Please provide the present macro you have setup as a reference to how you are using abook inside mutt.

Comment: @DravSloan I use `macro index,pager A "<pipe-message>abook --add-email<return>" "add the sender address to abook"` (just edited the question accordingly).